# Не могу сделать $python manage.py makemigrations , когда меняю DATABASE на другую в settings.py

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

Проект хорошо работает с БД на postgres. Без проблем.
Создаю локально новую БД postgres, указываю ее параметры в settings.py
запускаю:

```
$python manage.py makemigrations
```

получаю ошибку:

```
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "report_person" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t_person"."name", "report_person"."position" FROM "report_pe...
```

Пробовал указывать и SQLite3 в settings.py и удалял(и не удалял) папку migrations. Всегда ошибка та же. Просто попробывал создать таблицу в БД через консоль со столбцами как поля модели. Так ошибка, что "TABLE уже EXIST"
Подскажите, где я не догоняю?
И поэтому не получается на HEROKU сделать migrate

```
$ heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Та же самая ошибка

```
 django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "report_person" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t_person"."name", "report_person"."position" FROM "report_pe...
```

Хотя перед отправлением на хероку делаю успешный makemigrations в первую БД(единственную которую могу)
Нуб, сижу туплю столько времени.
Если начну другой проект, он мигрируется в новую БД...
Спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте миграции сделать последовательно, начиная с тех приложений, у которых нет зависимостей. В вашем случае, начиная с приложения, где есть модель `Person`

Comment: @IvanSemochkin да Иван, спасибо. Примерно так и решал проблему. Оказалось, что эта форма не позволяла:

Comment: @IvanSemochkin from django import form

q = models.Person.objects.all()
qty = range(len(q))
PersonForm = type('PersonForm',
                                (forms.Form,),
                                {'person'+'_'+str(q[i].id): forms.BooleanField(label=q[i].name,
                                        required=False) for i in qty})